# How to Print Letter P filled with Xs in python? (Output in description)

Tags: python

I want to printout this pattern of letter 'P':

```
XXXXXX
XX  XX
XXXXXX
XX
XX
```

(edit: I want this to be done from a looping statement especially FOR. Thank you)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Hi new contributor! :D I hope you are well. I have edited your question to remove external picture linking (it is generally discouraged in SO, with exceptions of data graphing). Please edit your question again and add an code example with an error or previous tries.  Look at this for guidance :https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DavidBuck Yes I have, I am very new to python so yeah, I couldnt do it so i asked

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example if you want to write it using loops:

```py
for j in range(5):
    for i in range(7):
        print("*" if i < 2 or j in [0, 2] or (i > 4 and j < 3) else " ", end='')
    print()
```

But please try experimenting yourself with loops and printing and see what happens.

Use `print("something", end='')` if you don't want to start a new line immediately after. The expression `"*" if i < 3 else " "` means that when `i < 3` you get a star, else you get a space.  You can get a similar result if you write:

```py
if i < 3:
    print("*")
else
    print(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can create multiline strings with triple quotes:

```
p = """
XXXXXX
XX  XX
XXXXXX
XX
XX
"""

print(p)
```

Comment: Albeit this is true, and therefore valid. My reinterpretation of the question is that the OP wants to make it via code. Or, to write a code that will print out P without any prior holding variable. This is often used as an practice tool to write algorithms. On other hand, if OP doesn't prove me right, this answer should be accepted as true.

Comment: @Danilo Sorry for less detail but i wanted it to be done from loop statement, it would be better if you would use FOR loop